# Passing string php to Jquery with spaces

Tags: php, jquery, encoding

I am trying to pass a string into a javascript from PHP but am failing miserably. From testing I can see its the whitespace that is making my test fail. How do I encode to pass to javascript properly. I tried %20 and a few more nothing seems to work.

Full Source

```
<script async  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function DemoOne(text) {
    $('#PageView').load('test.php?text=' + text);
}
</script>

<?php
    $message="hello world"; // fails
    // $message="hellotom"; // works the spaces cause failure

    echo "  <a href=\"javascript:DemoOne('$message');\" ><input class='btn' type='button' value='Test'></a>     
    <div id='PageView'></div>";

?>
```

Test Output test.php

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['text'];
?>
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you trying to put a clickable anchor link around a button? That does not make much sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<a href="DemoOne('<?php echo addslashes($message) ?>')">
    <input class='btn' type='button' value='Test'>
</a>
```

Working Code (updated your script as well):

```
<script async  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function DemoOne(text) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "GET",
       data: {text: text}
    }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
         $('#PageView').html(data); // display data
    });   
}
```

```
<?php
$message="hello world"; // fails
// $message="hellotom"; // works the spaces cause failure

echo "  <a href=\"javascript:DemoOne('$message');\" ><input class='btn' type='button' value='Test'></a>     
<div id='PageView'></div>";
```

?>